# How to get an hourly average number of unique persons using Hive?

Tags: sql, hive

I have this data in a table my_table:

```
camera_id     person_id         datetime
1             1                 2017-03-02 18:06:20
1             1                 2017-03-02 18:05:10
1             1                 2017-04-01 18:04:09
2             1                 2017-03-02 19:06:50
2             2                 2017-03-02 19:07:22
2             2                 2017-03-02 19:09:15
2             3                 2017-05-03 19:07:05
2             4                 2017-05-03 19:19:08
2             5                 2017-05-03 19:20:18
```

I need to count an hourly average number of **UNIQUE** persons detected by each camera.

For example let's take camera `2` and a time window from 19:00 to 20:00. The camera determined 2 unique visits on `2017-03-02` and 3 unique visits on `2017-05-03`. So, the answer is (2+3)/2 = 2.5

Expected result:

```
camera_id   HOUR   HOURLY_AVG_COUNT
1           18     1
2           19     2.5
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select      camera_id
           ,hour(datetime)                                                                                             as hour
           ,count(distinct person_id,date(datetime),hour(datetime)) / 
                count(distinct date(datetime),hour(datetime))    as hourly_avg_count 

from        my_table 

group by    camera_id
           ,hour(datetime) 

order by    camera_id
;
```

---

```
+-----------+------+------------------+
| camera_id | hour | hourly_avg_count |
+-----------+------+------------------+
|         1 |   18 | 1                |
|         2 |   19 | 2.5              |
+-----------+------+------------------+
```

P.s.

`date(datetime),hour(datetime)` can be also replaced by one of the following:

- `substr(cast(datetimeas string),1,13)`
- `date_format(datetime,'yyyy-MM-dd HH')`

Comment: Could you please take a look at my edit. Sorry, I have not explained well myself and was editing my question as proposed by Gordon Linoff.

Comment: `date(datetime)` does not work for me. Ìt gives me NULL. But `substr(cast(datetimeas string),1,13)` works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Very strange. What is the type of `datetime` and what Hive version do you use?

Comment: I use Hive 2.5 and `datetime` is of type `string`. This basically explains why `date(...)` does not work:)

Comment: @Dinosaurius - Yep. Why don't you define this column as a timestamp?

Comment: Well, I use tables migrated from external DB of PostgreSQL. After migrating with Sqoop there was probably some issue with data type. However `hour(datetime)` work fine.

Comment: @Dinosaurius - O.K. P.s. - there is no Hive 2.5

Comment: I see this when I start hive: `Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.5.3.0-37/0/hive-log4j.properties`

Comment: Try `select version()`

Comment: I have a question regarding the queries that you suggested. If you have an interest, the question is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928746/get-different-results-with-two-identical-queries